Characterization of multifunctions with globally asymptotically stable minimal invariant sets
Let $(X, d)$ be a compact connected metric space. Consider a compact-valued upper semicontinuous multifunction $F: X \rightrightarrows X$.  The reachable set $R[x]$ of $F$ from $x\in X$ is defined as:
$$R[x] = \overline{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F^{\circ n}[x]},$$
where $F^{\circ n}[x]$ denotes the $n$-fold composition of $F$ at $x$. A set $A \subseteq X$ is called an invariant set of $F$ if $F[A] = A$.  A minimal invariant set is a nonempty closed invariant set that does not contain any proper subset which is also a nonempty closed invariant set.
We say that $F$ has a globally asymptotically stable minimal invariant set $A \subseteq X$ if:

$A$ is a minimal invariant set of $F$.
For all $x\in X$:

$A$ is stable: for any open neighborhood $O$ of $A$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $A$ such that $F^{\circ n}[U] \subseteq O$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
$\omega[x] = A$, where $\omega[x] = \bigcap_{N\in \mathbb{N}} \overline{\bigcup_{n\geq N} F^{\circ n}[x]}$ is the omega limit set of $x$ under $F$.



It is known that if $R[x]$ is robust at every $x \in X$, that is
$$R[x] = \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0} \overline{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_\epsilon^{\circ n}[x]}$$
where $F_\epsilon [x] = \{ y \in X : d(y, F[x]) < \epsilon\}$, then $F$ possesses a globally asymptotically stable minimal invariant set.
Question. Are there any conditions on $F$ for the existence of a globally asymptotically stable minimal invariant set, without assuming robustness of the reachable set?
It seems like the assumptuon of robustness of reachable sets restricts the class of systems to which the theory applies. In particular, systems with discontinuous dynamics or abrupt state transitions often fail to satisfy this robustness criterion.
I am interested how this characterization might relate to the structure of $\omega$-limit sets in non-robust systems.
